# Можно ли запретить клонирование репозиториев по http/https и оставить возможность работы только по ssh?

Tags: ssh, gitlab

На сервере установлен gitlab, я хочу разрешить доступ к репозиториям только по ssh. таким образом над проектом смогут работать только те люди, чьи ключи я добавил в их профили в gitlab'e. В `gitlab.rb` я не нашел подобной опции. Есть ли возможность сделать такое ограничение?

Comment: А почему не использовать штатную систему привилегий?

Comment: В вашем случае, думаю, проще всего будет настроить nginx, чтобы по определенному URL он отдавал 403.

Comment: @Etki, а как будет выглядеть конфиг? можете отписаться в ответе? должно быть чтото вроде маски, отдающей 403 для всех адресов которые заканчиваются на `.git`? Или это жестко?

Comment: @sanu0074 да, тупо по паттерну сматчить. У вас вряд ли там идет сильный трафик, поэтому не должно особо сказаться на быстродействии. Сам конфиг сейчас написать не могу.

Comment: @Etki, такой почему-то не работает location ~ ^/.git$ { return 403; }

Comment: @sanu0074 уберите начальную каретку, этот вариант совпадет только с `/[один любой символ]git`

Comment: @Etki, всеравно пускает

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Штатными средствами GitLab это пока что сделать нельзя. Есть открытое [Issue](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/issues/3632) в Gitlab'e Gitlab'a, но пока так что-то никто не чешется.
В качестве временного костыля, есть [такое решение](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/gitlabhq/TwrunEd1cps/ThspDxT3t7UJ), однако я, как и его автор, не рекомендую менять код приложения.

**UPD**: вот [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/517311/209164) есть любопытное предложение выключить gitlab-workhorse (появился с версии 8 с чем-то, если мне не изменяет память), к сожалению не могу попробовать у себя, сервис в продакшне, но если у вас есть возможность - может сработать

Comment: При отключении gitlab-workhorse (`gitlab_workhorse['enable'] = false`) - невозможно зайти в сам gitlab, получаю `bad request`

Comment: @sanu0074 если это omnibus, то как там всё устроено я не знаю, но у меня на вручную установленном gitlab при незапущенном girlab-workhorse всё работало

Comment: @andreymal да примерно так же, просто все настройки живут в `/etc/gitlab/gitlab.rb`; параметр `gitlab_workhorse['enable']`, меняем `true` на `false` и запускаем `sudo gitlab-ctl reconfigure`

Comment: @beheerder, у меня omnibus, так вот я просто и поменял на true, и он лег