# Почему в gitlab добавлять ssh ключи могут все пользователи?

Tags: gitlab, ssh-key

По умолчанию каждый пользователь может добавлять свои ssh ключи в свой аккаунт в гитлабе. Но я хочу сделать эту возможность (добавлять ssh) доступной только админам. Это возможно как-то сделать? Или никак?

p.s. я хочу запретить доступ к репозиториям по http, и сделать возможным доступ только по ssh, для этого хочу в nginx рубить все запросы которые заканчиваются на `.git`

Comment: А зачем это? .-.

Comment: Чтобы не было доступа к репозиторию по http, достаточно просто не запускать gitlab-workhorse. А про ssh-ключи - зачем?

Comment: @andreymal, а за что отвечает gitlab-workhorse?

Comment: @D-side, для того чтобы не было доступа к репозиторию по http

Comment: Как можно понять из моего коммента, отвечает за доступ к репозиторию по http :)

Comment: @andreymal, здесь ответили что нельзя запретить доступ к репозиториям по http  средствами gitlaba: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/517249/%D0%9C%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%B2-%D0%BF%D0%BE-http-https-%D0%B8-%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82

Comment: Вас обманули) Пойду повозмущаюсь

Comment: @andreymal, а насчет создания ключей, я хочу это сделать для того чтобы никто не мог создать/изменить свои ключи. p.s. и для того чтобы вырубить workhouse достаточно раскоментить: gitlab_workhorse['enable'] = false? После того как я это сделал я не могу зайти в gitlab, получаю `bad request`

Comment: @sanu0074 а зачем вы хотите, чтобы никто не мог создать/изменить свои ключи? :)

Comment: И вы решили отрубить доступ по HTTP всем, а по SSH почти всем. Странная затея.

Comment: @andreymal, http небезопасно работать, особенно в чужой сети. Ну а насчет ключей, это у меня задача такая поставлена, насколько бы абсурдной она не была, нужно либо доказать что этого сделать невозможно, либо сделать

Comment: Добавил в gitlab-http.conf:

location  ~ ^/.git$ {
 return 403;
} и почему-то ничего не изменилось

Comment: @sanu0074, а может быть, вам не монстр gitlab нужен, а простенький gitolite? без всяких там веб-интерфейсов и вагона зависимостей/демонов?